# "got closed" vs "was closed" vs "has been closed"

Tags: grammar

> I would like to transfer my PF from A company to B company provided both the companies have proper digital signatures in the EPFO website. But the issue is, my previous company has been closed 6 months back.

Can we change the last sentence to the following, and which is preferred when?

1. But the issue is, my previous company closed 6 months back.
2. But the issue is, my previous company was closed 6 months back.
3. But the issue is, my previous company got closed 6 months back.

Answer (score 1):

- > my previous company has been closed 6 months back.

  This doesn't really work. It would make more sense to say "has been closed for 6 months."
- > my previous company closed 6 months back.

  This means that the company is out of business. 6 months ago, it went from being a normal company to one that is closed forever. This seems like the one you are looking for.
- > my previous company was closed 6 months back.

  This means that the company was in a closed state 6 months ago, but doesn't necessarily imply that it is closed right now. However, you *could* still use this to say that the company is closed permanently.
- > my previous company got closed 6 months back.

  This implies that the company was shut down by an external source. The company didn't close itself, but it got closed (by someone/something). It also means the company is closed permanently.

Comment: was closed, got closed is the same thing in different registers.